# Relationship between modules and maximal ideals of a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let  $A$ be an integral domain, $M$ an $A$-module, and $m\in M$. Now for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ there exists an $n\notin \mathfrak{m}$ such that $nm=0$. Why does this mean that $m=0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Show that the ideal generated by $n\notin\mathfrak m$, when $\mathfrak m$ runs over the maximal ideals of $A$, is the whole ring.